# GSON Field Naming, auto-call method after instantiation

Tags: android, gson

For example i have class:

```
public static class News implements Comparable<News>, Parcelable {
        static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        @SerializedName("Published")
        public String DateStr;

        MyDate date;

        public void callItAfterInstantiate(){
            if(date == null){
               java.util.Date parsed;
               try {
                   parsed = df.parse(DateStr);
                   date = new MyDate(parsed.getTime());
               } catch (ParseException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

            }
        }

        {...}
}
```

I can instantiate it using GSON:

```
News news = gson.fromJson(json, News.class);
```

But date = null;

I need to auto-call `callItAfterInstantiate` after instantiation. Is it possible? Field `MyDate` just for example. In real project there is can be another logic that should be auto-calling after creation.

Or the one possible solution is to call method directly after instantiation?

```
news.callItAfterInstantiate();
```

Comment: Hi, don't you just need to parse the date string from your json to your Date object? if so i can give you a hint about how to do it

Comment: @medhdj will be good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, here is 2 ways to do that first one will tell default gson parser how to parse date objects

```
public static class News implements Comparable<News>, Parcelable {
        public static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");


        @SerializedName("Published")
        Date date;
//.....
}

//then you parse your data like this
final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
//use your date pattern 
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat(df.toPattern());
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
News news = gson.fromJson(json, News.class);
```

Second solution would be the use of `news.callItAfterInstantiate();` for that you must overide the `JsonDeserializer` [a very good tutorial](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/)

```
public class NewsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<News> {
    public final static String TAG = "NewsDeserializer";

    @Override
    public News deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        //json object is complete 
        final JsonObject jsonObj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        // Log.i(TAG, jsonObj.toString());
        News news = new News();
        //parse your data here using JsonObject see the documentation it's pretty simple

        news.callItAfterInstantiate();
        return news;
    }
}
//then to parse you data
final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(News.class, new NewsDeserializer());
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
News news = gson.fromJson(json, News.class);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: In this JSON i have data in different  date format =/

Comment: ah, you can define a deserializer for your MyDate class if you want then register it as we did for NewsDeserializer . Or in the NewsDeserializer(second solution) after parsing the String date you create your MyDate object